# `or` and `&` in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, the infix operators `or` and `&` are defined as synonyms for `||` and `&&`, resp.  I like the first group of operators because they are a little easier to type, and they make me think I'm learning something different from conventional languages.

Unfortunately, both `or` and `&` are marked as deprecated in the manual.  I'd like to know

1. when this started, and
2. why this is so.

If the designers of OCaml have wrote a rationale for this design decision, I'd like to know where it is located.  I'd appreciate for your help.

As a side note, here's what I thought:

*Argument 1*.  `||` and `&&` are more friendly to former programmers of C and its descendants.

*Counter-argument 1*.  OCaml is in few ways similar to C.  It makes little sense to make it look like C in this particular regard only.

*Argument 2*.  It is more desirable to have similar symbols for both conjunction and disjunction.

*Counter-argument 2*.  In natural languages, we only had a special symbol, &, for conjunction and not for disjunction, and we were happy with that for centuries.  Besides, some textbooks in logic, including *Mathematical Logic* by Shoenfield, use entirely different symbols for disjunction and conjunction, viz., & and ∨.

Comment: Looking at the Changes file that comes with the distribution, I see that `&&` and `||` were added in Caml Special Light 1.13, which was released on Jan 4, 1996. So around 18 years ago. I don't know the answers to your questions, unfortunately :-)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Thank you.  Were `&` and `or` deprecated back then, shortly after the alternatives were added?

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to dig up any more info in my brief searches. There are some old OCaml hands here, maybe they will remember the details. It has been a *long* time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was marked as deprecated in [2001](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/commit/ef3d334d4a207ad31d9c7f74f4cc3d5259047e49/stdlib/pervasives.mli#diff-2fc253f6c4a29312d385687f6f1d37e5L178).

I am not aware of any design rationale for this, probably C similarity was the main driving point. Also, `or` and `&` are keywords in [jocaml](http://jocaml.inria.fr) - that might have been one of the reasons to discourage their use in regular OCaml.

Comment: It's interesting to note that `&` became deprecated first; `or` became deprecated in 2002.

Comment: It's sad to hear using `&` and `or` have different meanings in a dialect of OCaml.  Should I be really away from these deprecated operators? What mess can they cause?

Comment: They are deprecated, keep away from them, cannot really stress it more. BTW there is a on-by-default warning for deprecated features in 4.01. Treat them as if to be removed in some future release [ in 10 more years? :) ].